# Copying structures into a dynamically allocated array of structures

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc, realloc

I'm trying to copy over a structure to an array of structures.

I have a graph structure that has a field of a dynamically allocated array of vertices called

```
vlist
```

and a integer storing the number of vertices in the vlist.

Vertices have a name array as their inner field. 
The function I am getting an error, takes a graph and a string and adds a vertex to that graph with that string as the name for the vertex.

Here is the function:

```
int add_vertex(Graph *graph, const char name[]){

if(name && graph){

/*Allocating space for new vertex*/
vertex *new_vert = malloc(sizeof(vertex));

/*Allocating space for vertex name*/
  new_vert->name = malloc(strlen(name)+1);

 /*Copying new vertex name to newly allocated vertex*/
  strcpy(new_vert -> name, name);

 /*Adding a new space to vertex list*/
  graph -> vlist = realloc(graph-> vlist, sizeof(graph -> vlist) + sizeof(vertex));
  graph -> num_verts += 1;
  graph -> vlist[graph->num_verts] = new_vert;

    return 1; 
}
 else{
   return 0; 
 }
```

I am getting the error for the line:

```
  graph -> vlist[graph->num_verts] = new_vert;
```

Error:

```
incompatible types when assigning to type 'vertex' from type 'struct vertex *'
```

I'm assuming this means that I'm copying values into the dynamic array incorrectly, but I can't figure out why.

my Vertex is defined in a header file as :

```
typedef struct vertex{
  char *name;
} vertex
```

Any help at all would be great, thank you!

EDIT:

Definition of graph

```
typedef struct Graph {
  vertex *vlist;
  int num_verts; 
} Graph;
```

Comment: You are coy about what `Graph` and `vlist` are, and I suspect `sizeof(graph -> vlist)` is the size of a pointer, not the size of an array pointed to. Plainly `realloc(graph-> vlist, sizeof(graph -> vlist) + sizeof(vertex));` is wrong.

Comment: Instead of describing in English the decleration of `Graph`, why won't you copy and paste it?

Comment: `graph -> vlist[graph->num_verts] = *new_vert;`?

Comment: The *definition* of the type `Graph` is kind of essential to the question...

Answer (score 1):

The `vlist` member is an array of structure, not an array of pointers to structures.

Solution: Don't allocate `new_vert` dynamically, instead just declare it as an ordinary structure:

```
vertex new_vert;
```

Then it should work fine.

Remember to modify the member-access from `->` to `.`.

Comment: Now I am getting an invalid intializer error on the line where I declare vertex new_vert;